# Setting default value of a drop down menu in nuke with python

Tags: python, nuke

I am relatively new to python still, and I have been trying to write some simple things do nuke overrides for my work style. One of them being a remove node.

```
import nuke

def removeOverride():
    nuke.thisNode()["operation"].setValue("keep")
    nuke.thisNode()["channels"].setValue("rgb")
##Adds end lined commands to run when node is created by the user.

nuke.addOnUserCreate(removeOverride, nodeClass = "remove")
```

The above code is my attempt to change the values in the operations knob to keep instead of the nuke default of remove. As in my work flow I find it easier to just tell it which channels I want I want to keep.

Comment: The code I posted is my overriding method? And my question is how to actually get it to change values that are in a drop down menu inside the nod? I could not get my method to change the values of the knob if it is inside a drop down menu.

Comment: Also forgot to mention this is in my menu.py file.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: I’ll try once I get back to my computer. Just in reading it, it reads as if it will only work on a single node named remove1 and not any subsequent nodes created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one. Use this code for nodes with specific names:

```
def removeOverride():
    nuke.toNode("Remove1")['operation'].setValue('keep')
    nuke.toNode("Remove1")['channels'].setValue('rgb')

nuke.addOnUserCreate(removeOverride(), nodeClass='Remove') 

# use UpperCamelCasing for any class name ('Blur','Read','Remove')
```

Also for any subsequent nodes created, use this code:

```
def removeOverride():
    for node in nuke.allNodes():
        if node.Class() == "Remove":
            node["operation"].setValue("keep")
            node["channels"].setValue("rgb")

removeOverride()
# OR
nuke.addOnUserCreate(removeOverride(), nodeClass='Remove')
```

And the last configuration using `nuke.selectedNodes()` and `nuke.thisNode()` methods is suitable for selected nodes in the DAG:

```
def removeOverride():

    thisNode = nuke.thisNode()
    rootDAG = nuke.root()

    with rootDAG:
        allNodesSelected = nuke.selectedNodes()
    try:
        allNodesSelected.remove(thisNode)
    except:
        pass

    for node in allNodesSelected:
        node["operation"].setValue("keep")
        node["channels"].setValue("rgb")

    return allNodesSelected

nuke.addOnUserCreate(removeOverride(), nodeClass='Remove')
```

Comment: Okay I tried the second one and it works just maybe a little too good. It is changing the every remove in the script to have those values. And that might cause problems down the road if there is a chance that a single node needs to be left on remove and a different channel set. Which is why I was trying to do it using a nuke.thisNode() function so that as each remove was created it was changed only on creation and not as more might be created. Hmm...

Comment: Yeah I’ll have to figure a new way around doing this. For now I’ll use the for in method you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to consider using knob defaults instead of callbacks for this.

In your `init.py` (or `menu.py` if you only want it to apply to new nodes created in GUI sessions):

```
nuke.knobDefault('Remove.operation', 'keep')
nuke.knobDefault('Remove.channels', 'rgb')
```